# Adjunction correspondence for Blow up of double point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, blow-ups

Let $C$ a curve over an algebr closed field $k$ with a singular double point singularity at $x$ and $\pi: C' \to C$ the blowup in $x$ and let $x_1,x_2 \in C'$ be the two points over $x$.

Why holds for every invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ on $C$ the following identity:

$$\operatorname{Hom}(\mathfrak{m}_x, \mathcal{L}) \cong H^0(C', \pi^* \mathcal{L})  $$

where we invterpret the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_x \subset \text{Frac}(C)$ naturally as ideal sheaf. [Here](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1969__36__75_0.pdf) the source  (bottom p 77)

By definition of blowup in $x$ the image $\pi^{-1}\mathfrak{m}_x$ of the pullback is invertible in $C'$. Naively, we can construct from a map $f: \mathfrak{m}_x  \to \mathcal{L}$ via application of $\pi^*$ and precomposition a map $\mathcal{O}_{C'} \to \pi^{-1}\mathfrak{m}_x \otimes_{\pi^{-1}\mathcal{O}_C} \mathcal{O}_{C'} = \pi^*\mathfrak{m}_x \to \mathfrak{m}_x \mathcal{L}$.

That's a map in one direction since $H^0(C', \pi^* \mathcal{L})= \text{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_{C'} , \pi^* \mathcal{L})$. Note, here I  nothing used about blowup.

Firstly, is this a correct construction? And how I pass to other direction? Maybe there is also Serre duality tacitly involved? If yes, is in this situation an explicit relation between dualizing sheaves of $C$ and $C'$?